# Null after @InjectMocks

Tags: java, null, mocking, mockito, inject

I am having some troubles passing a dependency while unit testing with JUnit.

Consider these pieces of code:

This is the dependacy injecton into the class which i want to test, lets call it Controller.

```
@Inject private FastPowering fastPowering;
```

And this is the unit test:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class ControllerTest {

@Mock
FastPowering fastPower;

@InjectMocks
Controller controller;

@Test
public void test() {
    assertEquals(
            (controller.computeAnswer(new BigDecimal(2), 2)).longValue(),
            (long) Math.pow(2, 2));
    }
}
```

It seems that fastPower is null, please explain how to fix that.
Null pointer exception , because of calling the @injected field (fastPower) inside the .computeAnswer method)

Edit:

Solved i should have read about the difference between @Mock and @Spy...

Due to a lot of comments I am adding some more context to the solution

The difference is that in mock, you are creating a complete mock or fake object while in spy, there is the real object and you just spying or stubbing specific methods of it. While in spy objects, of course, since it is a real method, when you are not stubbing the method, then it will call the real method behavior.

If fastPower is annotated as *@Mock* it's methods are dummy, yet *controller.computeAnswer* depends on them to compute. One must provide behaviour.

If spy is used without stubbing then the real implementation of *fastPower* is being executed which eventually returns desired value.

Another option is to use a real *FastPowering* instance

https://github.com/mockito/mockito/wiki/Using-Spies-(and-Fakes)
https://github.com/mockito/mockito/wiki/Mocking-Object-Creation

And some stackoverflow thread outlining the difference [Mocking vs. Spying in mocking frameworks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12827580/mocking-vs-spying-in-mocking-frameworks)

Short Answer: Replace `@Mock` with `@Spy` and should be working fine

Comment: Is the method static or final?

Comment: it is neather final nor static

Comment: "Solved i should have read about the difference between @Mock and @Spy..." would it be possible to post and accept your solution as an answer? That may help other users with the same problem and close this thread.

Comment: Please describe the solution rather than a silly clue.

Comment: @radpet kindly add the solution you found as an answer.

Answer (score 33):

Use `MockitoAnnotations.initMocks` to initiate the `@Mock` and `@InjectMocks` objects. Your test would look something like:

```
@Mock
FastPowering fastPower;

@InjectMocks
Controller controller;

@Before
public void setup() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
}

@Test
public void test() {
    ....
}
```

Comment: The same issue, NPE after @InjectMocks and MockitoAnotations.initMocks(this)

Comment: @VB_ were you able to resole this issue? if yes, how?

Comment: Solution does not work

Comment: I was able to get it working with BeforeEach instead of Before

Comment: init mock looks to be deprecated

Answer (score 10):

I was using the wrong `@Test` annotations, If you want to use `@InjectMocks` and `@Mock` in your Mockito Test, then you should

1. add `@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)` annotation on your test class
2. annotate your test methods with `@Test (org.junit.jupiter.api.Test)` and not the `@Test (org.junit.Test)` annotation. be careful with the import that you are using for this annotation.

This works on `mockito-core:3.6.28`

Comment: Thank you! Why they would keep these incompatible annotations so closely named is beyond me.

Answer (score 4):

After debugging I found a reason. This is because of the `org.powermock.core.MockRepository#instanceMocks` collection. It doesn't contain a mock for a field with `@InjectMocks` annotation (`Controller controller` in your case).
To solve it try to use the `@Spy` annotation in the field declaration with initializing of them and `@PrepareForTest` above the class declaration:

```java
@PrepareForTest(Controller.class)
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class ControllerTest {
    
    @Mock
    FastPowering fastPower;
    
    @Spy
    @InjectMocks    
    Controller controller = new Controller();
    
    @Test
    public void test() {
        //...
    }
}
```

In my case it helped. Using of the `Mockitoannotations.initMocks(this)` method is not required, it doesn't affect the result.

Answer (score 3):

I fixed this by removing the extraneous new instance I was creating in my @Before method (see example below). It was also fixed by moving `MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this)` after initializing `myClass`, but since Mockito created `myClass` anyway, that solution was inferior.

```java
// Note - you may need @mock(name="foo") to help mockito differentiate props
//        if they have the same type
@Mock
private Thing something;

@InjectMocks
private MyClass myClass;

@Before
 public void setUp() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this); // Moving this below the next line fixed it...
    myClass = new MyClass() // But just remove this line and let Mockito do the work
}
```

Comment: Errr, in such case you don't really Inject your `MyCLass`, but rather directly create an instance of it. So, `@InjectMocks` becomes completely useless with it.

Answer (score 2):

Useful to note that the use of `MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);` needs to come at the **end** of your `@Before`/`setUp()` method.

If it is at the top of your `setUp()` then it may cause other mocked classes to not be initialised.

I ran into this error myself just now and placing `.initMocks` at the end of my `@Before` solved my issue.

Answer (score -1):

2 more things to check:

1. Mocking the behaviours of fastPower. What should this mocked object return, when it methods are called? i.e. when(fastPower.doSomething()).thenReturn(some_kind_of_object);
2. Check if the controller.computeAnswer() does not return NULL for the input of new BigDecimal(2), 2)).longValue(), (long) Math.pow(2, 2).