# JUnit test always returning null

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I am writing a JUnit test case for my code, but the Mockito is always returning `null`

```
@Component
public class ConnectorImpl {

    public String returnString(String inte) {

        String x = testing();
        return x;
    }

    public String testing() {
        return "test";
    }
}
```

Test class

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class ConnectorImplTest  {

    @Mock public ConnectorImpl connector;

    @Test
    public void testLoggedInRefill() throws Exception {

        Mockito.when(connector.testing()).thenReturn("test");


        String x = connector.returnString("8807");

        assertEquals("8807", x);
    }

}
```

When I am calling `connector.returnString("8807");`, it is always returning `null`. Is there anything I am doing wrong? I am new to JUnit.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mockito - spy vs mock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28295625/mockito-spy-vs-mock)

Comment: tl;dr: you want a `Spy`, not a `Mock`. As an aside: instead of mocking `testing()`, you should mock the call to `returnString("8807");`(then you can keep using `Mock`s)

Answer (score 0):

One way you can test your method `returnString` is as :

```
// mock 'returnString' method call
Mockito.when(connector.returnString(anyString()).thenReturn("test"); 
// assert that you've mocked succesfully
assertEquals("test", connector.returnString("8807"));
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your code, you are mocking your `ConnectorImpl`

So it is an empty object and it means that it is up to you to specifically `when(...).then(...)` any functionality that you like to test.

BTW - if you are testing the `ConnectorImpl` then you should not mock it, but actually use the real bean. You should mock the beans that `ConnectorImpl` is using.

So I would suggest your code look maybe like that:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class ConnectorImplTest  {

    public ConnectorImpl connector = new ConnectorImpl(...);

    @Test
    public void testLoggedInRefill() throws Exception {
        String x = connector.returnString("8807");
        assertEquals("8807", x);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are mocking the object and you do not specify any behaviour for the returnString method of the mocked object. As you did for testing(), you can do the same for returnString() method:

`when(connector.returnString(anyString())).thenReturn("text")`

On the other hand why do you need ti mock this class?