# Mockito keeps calling the real method and not mock it

Tags: java, spring, junit, mockito

I'm trying to create a test where I have to mock a method inside the class that I want to test. But it keeps calling the real method, but I want mock it.

The method that I want to mock is

> extractSecretValue(String path)

I know it's not mocking the method because there is a "println", and it's printing.

What am I doing wrong?

I'm using JUnit 5

The class that I want to test:

```
    @Configuration
    public class RestTemplateConfig {

        @Value("${******}")
        private String keystore;

        @Value("${******}")
        private String identificador;

        @Value("${******}")
        private String token;

        @Bean
        public RestTemplate restTemplate() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyManagementException {
            SSLContext context = null;

            context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.2");
            context.init(null, null, null);

            List<Header> headers = new ArrayList<>();
            headers.add(new BasicHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + extractSecretValue(token)));

            CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().setSSLContext(context).setDefaultHeaders(headers)
                    .build();

            HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory hcchr = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(httpClient);

            hcchr.setConnectionRequestTimeout(10000);

            return new RestTemplate(hcchr);

        }

        public String extractSecretValue(String path) {

            System.out.println("Test1");
            Path secretPath = Paths.get(path);
            String value = "";
            try (Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(secretPath)) {
                value = lines.collect(Collectors.joining());
            } catch (IOException ignored) {
                throw new ApplicationException(ignored);
            }
            return value.isEmpty() ? path : value;
        }

    }
```

The Test class:

```
    @ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
    public class RestTemplateConfigTest {

        @Test
        public void return_restTemplateConfig() {

            RestTemplateConfig restTemplateConfig = new RestTemplateConfig();

            RestTemplateConfig restTemplateMock;

            RestTemplate restTemplate;

            restTemplateMock = Mockito.spy(restTemplateConfig);

            try {
                when(restTemplateMock.extractSecretValue(anyString())).thenReturn("423424");
                restTemplate = restTemplateMock.restTemplate();
            } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | KeyManagementException e) {
                throw new ApplicationException(e);
            }

        }

    }
```

I've already tried this too:

```
doReturn("2332").when(restTemplateMock).extractSecretValue(anyString());
```

Comment: Your mock does not work because it was arranged to expect `anyString` but when invoked `token` is *null* causing the arrangement to not match and default back to the actual method call.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use `when(...).thenReturn(...)` the real method will still be invoked
*(from Mockito, which is not relevant for your test)*,
but that should not happen when you use the `doReturn(...).when(...)` notation instead.

The problem in your test is that `token` is *null* and your `anyString()` does not match that as it only matches non-null strings.

Use `any()` instead, which matches **anything**, including *nulls*.

Combine that with the `doReturn(...).when(...)` and your test should succeed.

Comment: Also please consider renaming your `spy` object. It is different from a (simple) `Mock` so using a name that indicates that improves the readability.

Comment: I didn't know "when() thenReturn" would call the real method on spyed objects. I will rename the RestTemplateMock to RestTemplateSpy. Thank you.

Comment: This behaviour only applies when `spy` is used instead of `mock`, as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29394497/11514534).

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want the actual methods to be called, then you should be using Mockito.mock() and not Mockito.spy().

you should update your test class to use :

```
restTemplateMock = Mockito.mock(RestTemplateConfig.class);
```

Comment: If I do it I think the real method restTemplate() won't be tested. or will it be? I mean, I just want to mock the extractSecretValue.

Comment: Both spy() and mock() can be used to mock objects whereas spy() is a partial mock. The difference between them is better explained here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28295625/mockito-spy-vs-mock.
Since you are stubbing the method using when()..then() , there is essentially no difference if you use spy(). @Second is correct that since the token was null, actual method invocation was happening.

Comment: I did it, but my test coverage didn’t update for my class when I used mock, only spy works for me. I stubbed the method extractSecretValue, but I want to test the real method restTemplate.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't mocked your RestTemplateConfig, you've instantiated it.

What you want is:

restTemplateMock = Mockito.spy(new RestTemplateConfig());

Comment: It doesn't work, keeps calling the real method. But I instantiated restTemplateConfig and then I did Mockito.spy(restTemplateConfig). Should be the same thing.