# Java unit test - exception not being thrown

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing, junit, mockito

Trying to write a test that will call my method, when that method makes a call to another method we will throw a custom exception i have made. Here i have simplified it all

2 functions

```
public MyJsonResponse hello() {
        MyJsonResponse response = new MyJsonResponse();
        response.setErrorMessage("1");
        response.setStatus("some status");
        response.setData("1");
        response.setHttpResponse(200);
        try{
            hi();
            return response;
        }catch (MyServiceException e) {
            response.setErrorMessage(e.getMessage());
            response.setStatus("error creating");
            response.setData("2");
            response.setHttpResponse(e.getResponseStatus());
            return response;
        }

    }

    public String hi() throws  MyServiceException{
        LOG.error("Exception");
        return "yea";
    }
```

The test I have written is this

```
    @Test
    public void myTest() throws Exception {

        given(service.hi()).willAnswer( invocation -> { throw new MyServiceException("abc msg",511); });
        MyJsonResponse actual = service.hello();

        Assert.assertNotNull(actual);
        assertEquals(511, actual.getHttpResponse());
    }
```

But unfortunately the result is as follows

```
java.lang.AssertionError: 
Expected :511
Actual   :200
```

Comment: Not familiar with the BDD style of Mockito but are you sure that the exception is actually being thrown and handled?  Have you tried debugged the test case and/or just used some simple tracing statements to check?

Comment: Yea I've debugged, it's not being thrown and handled. I am trying to figure out why that is. Also open to alternative ways of testing this.

Comment: The `given` clause does look suspicious, should perhaps be `willThrow(new MyServiceException(...)).given(service).hi()` or something like that?

Comment: Tried that but got - Checked exception is invalid for this method!

Comment: Ah hadn't noticed the `hi` method is a member of the class under test, I'd assumed it was a separate service.  Presumably you create a *concrete* instance of `service` in the setup/before method of your test, so you can't stub that method (not without using nasty partial spy mocks anyway).  Easier to extend the service class and override the `hi` method rather than mocking it?

Comment: Don't really want to make change to the service just need to write a test for the way it is if that makes sense.

Comment: What does your `hi()` method *really* do? Currently it just logs something and returns a string. Is there any method invocation of a dependency in your `hi()` method which you can mock and let them throw an exception? Your test fails because your `service` is not a mock and therefore you can not set any mocked behaviour.

Comment: Otherwise you should try to spy your service:  `var serviceSpy = Mockito.spy(service);` 

`willThrow(new MyServiceException("abc msg",511)).given(serviceSpy).hi();`

Comment: The real method that hi represents does a lot I was thinking it would be easier to avoid mocking a lot of the calls and methods in there

Comment: Have you tried the `spy` approach? Otherwise why not mocking the internals of your `hi()` method? E.g. if `hi()` relies on a dependency which you can mock, inject in your service and mock the method which results in an exception?

Comment: Are you sure you are calling `hello()` real implementation, and not an empty mock ? How is `service` instanciated ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, be sure that you are using a [`spy`](https://javadoc.io/static/org.mockito/mockito-core/3.11.0/org/mockito/Mockito.html#spy-java.lang.Class-) as you want to use the actual code for some methods of your mocked service and just stubbing specific methods of it. Please, see for instance [this related SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28295625/mockito-spy-vs-mock) about the subject.

Also, consider modifying your test definition to use [`willThrow`](https://javadoc.io/static/org.mockito/mockito-core/3.11.0/org/mockito/BDDMockito.html#willThrow-java.lang.Throwable...-) instead of `willAnswer`: as pointed out by @eis, you can still use the later, but the former is more straightforward.

Your code will look similar to this:

```
@Test
public void myTest() throws Exception {
  MyService service = spy(MyService.class);

  willThrow(new MyServiceException("abc msg",511))
    .given(service)
    .hi()
  ;

  // As pointed out by @eis, you can still use willAnswer
  // willAnswer(
  //   invocation -> { throw new MyServiceException("abc msg",511);}
  // )
  //   .given(service)
  //   .hi()
  // ;

  
  MyJsonResponse actual = service.hello();

  Assert.assertNotNull(actual);
  assertEquals(511, actual.getHttpResponse());
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't think willThrow vs willAnswer would make any difference in this case, even though using willThrow is more straight forward

Comment: I agree with you @eis. The actual solution has to do with the use of `spy`. I will modify the answer with your feedback. Thank you very much for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

regarding what you explain and what your code look like, I am not sure if I have well understood.
Thus, if you want that, your hi() : function throws an exception.
You have to make it first throws an exception. Take a look at code below!

```
 public String hi() throws  MyServiceException{
        /*LOG.error("Exception");//No don't just log, throw a real exception as below*/
       throw new MyServiceException("text here, if your constructor support it or nothing otherwise")
     /*return "yea";//Nothing to return? we have just break the code by throwing the exception above*/
    }
```

After that, please be very sure that your 'MyServiceException.getHttpResponse()' will really return 511

Answer (score -1):

For this test to make sense, your hi() call should be done calling another service that you stub/mock in your test class. You're not doing that, so this approach won't work.

You wrote "the real method that hi represents does a lot", so it's about time you extract that to another service.