# Spring bean methods don't use the field value injected by ReflectionTestUtils.setField

Tags: java, spring, testing, junit

I have a spring project, which contains a class called `EnvUtils`:

```java
package com.example;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.util.Objects;

@Component
public class EnvUtils {

    @Value("${env}")
    private String env;

    /**
     * Develop environment
     */
    public boolean isDev() {
        return Objects.equals(env, "dev");
    }

    /**
     * Production environment
     */
    public boolean isProd() {
        return Objects.equals(env, "prod");
    }

}
```

I wrote a simple test, which set `env`'s value to `dev`, and checked the result of `isDev()`:

```java
package com.example;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.mockito.junit.jupiter.MockitoExtension;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockBean;
import org.springframework.test.util.ReflectionTestUtils;

@SpringBootTest
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class MainControllerTests {

    @MockBean
    private EnvUtils envUtils;

    @Test
    void fieldTest() {
        ReflectionTestUtils.setField(envUtils, "env", "dev");
        Assertions.assertTrue(envUtils.isDev());
    }

}
```

The test should pass because the value of `env` is `dev`, which means `envUtils.isDev()` should definitely return `true`. However, this test failed. I debugged it and found that `envUtils.env` was `dev`, as expected, but `envUtils.isDev()` returned false. How could it be? Have I done something wrong?

Comment: How did this test fail? What is your actual test? There is no point to test `ReflectionUtils.setField()`. Also you have `MockitoExtension` but you are using `@MockBean`? Should this even be a `@SpringBootTest`?

Answer (score 2):

You are mocking `EnvUtils` class, so the method `isDev` is mocked also, the real method of the class will not be invoked.

In your case, you don't need `@MockBean`, remove it. And don't forget to initialize the `envUrils` object using default constructor.

```
@SpringBootTest
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class MainControllerTests {

    private EnvUtils envUtils = new EnvUtils();

    @Test
    void fieldTest() {
        ReflectionTestUtils.setField(envUtils, "env", "dev");
        Assertions.assertTrue(envUtils.isDev());
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You mocked whole EnvUtils class.
If you change it to Spy it would be work.
Read this:[mock vs spy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12827580/mocking-vs-spying-in-mocking-frameworks)

Try this:

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class MainControllerTests {

    @SpyBean
    private EnvUtils envUtils;

    @Test
    void fieldTest() {
        ReflectionTestUtils.setField(envUtils, "env", "dev");
        Assertions.assertTrue(envUtils.isDev());
    }

}
```